# Update NCLOB column with a XML of more than 4000 characters in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table with column name `message` which is of type NCLOB and `ID` which is of type varchar2

I want to update the message of a particlular ID. I am using the following query

```
update table_name set message='<<long XML Message>>' where ID=value
```

I am getting the following error :

```
Error at Command Line:6 Column:38
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01704: string literal too long
01704. 00000 -  "string literal too long"
*Cause:    The string literal is longer than 4000 characters.
*Action:   Use a string literal of at most 4000 characters.
       Longer values may only be entered using bind variables.
```

I tried storing the xml into a variable and updating the column to this variable, but of no use

Comment: How much longer than 4000 characters is the string? If it will always be less than 32k then you can assign that to a CLOB variable in PL/SQL and then use that for the insert. Otherwise you'd have to build the CLOB up in chinks of up to 32k which is a little bit more work. What did you try with a variable, and why didn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has a limit on the length of literal strings, you are hitting that limit. You can break it up into 4000 character chunks.  This might do it for you. I can't test it at the moment.

```
update table_name set message= '<4K>' || '<4K>' || '<4K>' where ID=value
```

It looks like the above will not work.

So lets try this, with 1K blocks:

```
update table_name set message= '<1st 1K>' where ID=value;
update table_name set message= message || '<2nd 1K>' where ID=value;
update table_name set message= message || '<3rd 1K>' where ID=value;
update table_name set message= message || '<4th 1K>' where ID=value;
```

I was able to add a message length of 80K.
I just stopped after that, no errors.

Comment: Nope. It will try to assemble the multiple 4k strings into one before trying to assign the final value to the column, so it will still error. With a different error, but it still won't work, unfortunately.

Comment: You are right, the first method doesn't work, but I don't give up... it seems if you add a smaller string to the NCLOB using an update, it works!

Comment: Interesting; I didn't think that would work either. [But it does](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1aa14/3).